# How to test browser Compatibility in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cross-browser

I used Microsoft XP as operation system for web design and development for 1 year. But now I am switching to Ubuntu (linux).

For Windows OS we have Microsoft’s SuperPreview for testing compatibility in different versions of IE.

Please specify the list of such utilities or tools which provide such support in Linux, specifically for Ubuntu.

Comment: re: specifically for Ubuntu. Programs are generally distro agnostic in ljnux. Everything redhat will run on Ubuntu as long you compile against the proper libraries for the OS. Different distros have different packaging systems though. Example: .deb, .rpm for programs, but those are just the OS's way of compiling the program against the proper libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to test IE compatibility on Linux, you have a few options:

1. Windows on a Virtual Machine (eg: [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)) with multiple IEs installed
2. [IEs4Linux](http://www.tatanka.com.br/ies4linux/page/Main_Page)
3. [Wine + Winetricks](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks)

In order of personal preference (VM is my favorite option).

Other than that, you can use install Firefox, Opera and Chrome on Ubuntu. There's no native version of Safari, but you should be fine since it uses the same rendering engine as Chrome (WebKit).